# Why does my PyQt program gets executed 2 times

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
class MyThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self,a,b,parent=None):
        super(QThread,self).__init__()
        self.a1 = a
        self.b1 = b

    def run(self):
         c = int(self.a1)+int(self.b1)
         time.sleep(5)
         print("Add = %s" %(c))

class MainWindow(QMainWindow,Ui_Form):

 def __init__(self):
     super().__init__()
     self.setupUi(self)
     self.radioButton_1.toggled.connect(lambda:self.test(self.radioButton_1))


 def test(self,rbutton):
      print('1')   
      add = rbutton.text()[-1]
      radioname = "RadioButton" + str(add)
      if rbutton.text() == radioname:
                                if add == "1":
                                        a = self.lineEdit.text()
                                        b = self.lineEdit_7.text()
                                        self.thread = MyThread(a,b)
                                        self.thread.start()
```

1st question, when i input e.g. 10 and 10 in my lineEdit's i get this result.

```
1
1
Add = 20Add = 20
```

Why does it seem to run twice?

And 2nd question which is mind boggling to me. If i remove the `print('1')` when i press the radio button, gui crashes ("Python has stopped working")

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation in your example, and ensure that the code is at least sane. The line `self.thread.start(self,a,b)` makes no sense at all, and you are creating two threads with the same name. Also: why are the argument names reversed in the signature of `MyThread`? Please read the guidance on how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: That code never really executed, iv removed it from the example. Indentation is not a issue, nor is arguments reverse.... But i have edited it.

Comment: If it didn't execute, then how did you get that output or those errors? Anyway, the first question is trivial: the `toggled` signal will be emitted for every radio-button, checked or unchecked. The second question is not answerable, since the code you've provided cannot reproduce it (which is why I asked for an mcve).

Comment: Ty for ur help. What i did wrong was named the threads the same for each radio button.